# Can't go to my server's webpage using my external IP address from my local network

Tags: linux, networking

If I type the external IP address (obtained from [whatsmyipaddress](http://whatsmyipaddress.com)) while on the same network as the server, I get a "Page not found" error. I have to use the local IP address (192.168...) to load it correctly. I can also load it with the external IP if I'm not on the local network.

How can I fix this so that the external IP address will go to the server as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your router would need to support it, some do, some don't.

Most DNAT (port forwarding) home-office routers only forward connections coming in from the outside to the external IP/port to the internal server, connections from the internal network are ignored.

You may be able to do some "routing magic" (technical term) on your local PC to do a NAT routing to the local server IP for connections to the external server IP, something in the OUTPUT table with iptables (if you're running Linux).